The tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() still returns full dataset in its entirety
The full dataset for my CNN model is too large for the 12GB vRAM the GPU has and model.fit() throws OOM error when all of them is loaded. To solve this OOM problem, data generator is implemented as following:
def my_generator(image_patches, user_ids, binary_flags, batch_size): #<<==generator function. images_patches is the total patches created out of all training or testing images.
        
    for patch, user_id, binary_flag in zip(image_patches, user_ids, binary_flags):
        # Normalize image patches (e.g., divide by 255.0)
        patch = np.array(patch) / 255.0

        # One-hot encode the user_ids and binary_flags
        user_id_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(user_id, num_classes=len(USERID_LIST))  # return in np.array format
        binary_flag_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(binary_flag, num_classes=2)

        yield patch, user_id_one_hot, binary_flag_one_hot. #<<== only single data sample is yielded

Here is the return_dataset() defined to use the tf.data.Dataset.from_generator():
def return_dataset(data, window_size=(224, 224), step_size=112, shuffle_buffer_size=1000, prefetch_buffer_size=1):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    image_paths = './data/'+df['image_id'].values. #<<==image paths for all the images in dataset
    label_user_ids = df['label_user_id'].values
    label_binary_flags = df['label_binary_flag'].values

    temp_dataset = preprocess_image_patches(image_paths, label_user_ids, label_binary_flags, window_size, step_size)
    #temp_dataset = tuple(temp_dataset.map(augment_data_image))
    image_patches, user_ids, binary_flags = temp_dataset. #<<== the image_patches are all the image patches generated from the image_path.
    
    # Create TensorFlow dataset
    patch_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: my_generator(image_patches, user_ids, binary_flags), #(s for s in temp_dataset),
        output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32),
        output_shapes=((224, 224, 3), (len(USERID_LIST),), (2,))
    )
    
    # Shuffle, augment, batch, and prefetch the dataset
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)  # Shuffle data
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)  # Create batches
    patch_dataset = patch_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)  # Optimize for performance
    dataset_size = patch_dataset.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1). #check the size of the patch_dataset
    print(f"patch_dataset size in return_dataset() :", dataset_size.numpy()). ##<<==the patch_dataset size returned is the full dataset size which defeated the purpose of using from_generator()
    
    yield patch_dataset. #this is still a full dataset which caused OOM

Even though my_generator() only yield a single data sample/patch at one time, why dataset_size.numpy() above is still the full size of dataset (dataset_size x BATCH_SIZE) but not ONE BATCH_SIZE dataset as .batch() specified? Or there needs a for loop which loops through the patch_dataset from the from_generator() and feed the model.fit() with BATCH_SIZE of dataset.
